# A measure dispayed as a string in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I need to sum up certain measure (duration) according to project name and issue type as on the picture below, but what I'm getting is a non-specific string instead of expected number.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You are not adding the dimensions to viz, but instead you have added some field named `pname` to viz!  May only be helped further, if you'll elaborate with some sample data

Answer (score 0):

You need to put SUM(Duration) on text instead of detail.